# SASS Mixin Selector

Tags: sass, mixins

Is there a way to select mixins in Sass rules.

Can be useful for recursively nested classes. Say I want to extract:

```
.my_class
    margin-top: 1px
    &+.m y_class
        margin-top: 0
```

into

```
@mixin my_mixin
    margin-top: 1px;
    &+@any_class(my_mixin)
        margin-top: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for what you are trying to do?

Sass:

```
@mixin my_mixin
  margin-top: 1px
  & + &
    margin-top: 0

h1
  @include my_mixin
```

Generated CSS:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
h1 + h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```